# How can I fix a 'Subscript out of range' error when populating an array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to find out what wrong with my code and why it returns the above error.
The purpose of the code is to construct resArr that in the end must have 94 values, and when it ready I need to copy all the values to one row in worksheet.
The next code is only first step off the constructing and I already have the error.
wsPrm is the global variable and defined in another Sub, so it's correct.
I know that numbering of arrays starts from 0, that's the reason I defined it by ReDim function from 1.
The error comes from line : `resArr(year + 13) = dataArr(year + 1)`

```
Public Sub Simulate()

Dim term, tranche As Integer
Dim dataArr() As Variant, resArr(1 To 94) As Variant

noiterations = wsPrm.Range("iterations").Value
tranche = wsPrm.Range("tranche").Value
term = wsPrm.Range("Period").Value
Tresv = wsPrm.Range("Tresv").Value

For counter = 1 To noiterations
    ReDim dataArr(1 To term + 1)
    dataArr = wsSim.Range(wsSim.Cells(6, 43), wsSim.Cells(6 + term, 43)).Value
    For year = 0 To term
        resArr(year + 13) = dataArr(year + 1)
        resArr(year + 13 + 41) = dataArr(year + 1)
    Next year
Next counter
End Sub
```

Comment: `dataArr` is a 2-Dimension array `try dataArr(Year + 1,1)`

Comment: CDP1802
 - Thank you! I thought that if I assign to array values from column it must be one-dimensional array. Now, when i manage the array as two-dimensional everything works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I know that numbering of arrays starts from 0" - In most programming languages, yes. VBA, however, builds on COM, which uses a mishmash of array indexing. Excel usually uses 1-based indices (but there are exceptions, when it uses 0-base indexing), and in you code you can define arrays with 42-based indices (not that it made sense).

`ReDim dataArr(1 To term + 1)` is superfluous, you do not need to allocate memory, Excel does it for the arrays that it returns.

The expression `wsSim.Range(wsSim.Cells(6, 43), wsSim.Cells(6 + term, 43)).Value` (assuming that wsSim is also a global variable to a `Worksheet`) returns a two dimensional array, and both dimensions are 1-based:

```
v = wsSim.Range(wsSim.Cells(6, 43), wsSim.Cells(6 + term, 43)).Value
Debug.Print LBound( v, 1 ) ' Must be 1
Debug.Print UBound( v, 1 ) ' Must be 1 + term
Debug.Print LBound( v, 2 ) ' Must be 1
Debug.Print UBound( v, 2 ) ' Must be 1
```

I don't see where 94 comes from but if `term` is read from somewhere, it must be a calculated value, right?

Comment: Thank you! As i mentioned in the question, this code is only apart of bigger program, but here I mentioned only the relevant rows of code to be short. I thought that if I assign to array values from column it must be one-dimensional array. Now, when I manage the array as two-dimensional everything works perfect.